# Using verbal suffixes two times in a word

Tags: verbs, adverbs

I was messing around with verbs, and I was wondering what is the equivalent adverb for « Dum mi estis manĝinta ». So I thought of *manĝintinte*. But is this a correct word? And are manĝintonte and manĝontinte also correct? I decomposed them in « Dum mi estos manĝinta » and « Dum mi estis manĝonta ». But these adverbs look a bit silly, so I need some help. Thanks!

Comment: *Dum mi estis manĝinta* doesn't really make sense. Compare it with *while I had eaten*. There is no agreement  between *dum* and *estis ...inta*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, and to me it seems that you are mixing things.

**​1. The active *-ant/int/ont* and the passive *-at/it/ot* endings form participles, not verbs.**

The participles are used to:

- to describe things as adjectives

*la leganta homo* : the reading person

- to name things as nouns

*leginto* : one/person who has read

- to form non-finite clauses as adverbs

*Skribonte leteron li kolektis siajn skribilojn* : In order to write a letter he collected his pens.

While other word types are theoretically possible, like verbs *legantas*, those are in practice too complicated to understand and therefore can be regarded as avoidable.

**​2. Compound tenses are seldomly needed.**

The adjective participles can be used to form compound verb forms:

- *Mi estas manĝinta*
- *La pomo estis manĝita*

Since these forms use *esti* as the auxliary verb, they are to be regarded as descriptions of the action instead of the action itself. This may sound a minor thing, but can play a major in some contexts.

One of the early pioneers, Kazimierz Bein, influenced a lot on style. Thanks to his input we now mostly write *Mi manĝis pomon* instead of using compound tenses. Esperanto has its own verb aspects – see the prefix *ek-* and postfix *-ad* – but there is no aspect of continuous/non-continuous action as in English. Trying to express those English phenomenon with compound participle constructions is usually a bad idea right from the beginning and very often the result does not express what you intended to say.

**​3. Piling pre- and postfixes is not a good idea.**

While in theory you can pile as many pre- and postfixes as you wish, the practical limit is one pre- and two postfixes. More just make words unnecessary complicated to understand and are superfluous. This is formulated in *la principo de neceso kaj sufiĉo*.

So a word like *manĝintinte* with three postfixes (*manĝ + int + int + e*) is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 3):

> So I thought of manĝintinte. But is this a correct word?

No, it is not. The participle endings `-inte` (`-ante`, `-onte`) are always attached to a verb root. Otherwise they don't make any sense.

So, you cannot chain them like you just did: `manĝint-int-e` because the last `-inte` would be attached to `manĝint-` (not a verb root).